# Do maven repos support uber jars like other depedancies?

Tags: java, maven, artifactory

I want to package and deploy an uber jar to Maven repo like my other dependencies.

It looks like though by default, even though I'm using shade the uber jar is not deployed to `my-repo` when I run `mvn deploy`. How can I deploy my uber jar to a Maven repo to be able to download it for use later- or even reference the uber jar as a dependency in another POM?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <!-- Use shade to create uber jar -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>uber</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
          <id>my-repo</id>
          <name>my-repo</name>
          <url>https://blah.jfrog.io/blah/my-repo</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
          <id>my-repo</id>
          <name>my-repo</name>
          <url>https://blah.jfrog.io/blah/my-repo</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: Note that using an uber jar as dependency is risky unless you shade _all_ the included dependencies. Otherwise you easily run in class loading conflicts later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `<shadedArtifactAttached>` and `<shadedClassifierName>` properties in shade plugin configuration section.
Take a look at this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html

In the project you have to configure `<maven-shade-plugin>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>uber-jar</shadedClassifierName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In a dependent project you can use that artifact as a dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <classifier>uber-jar</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: oh ok so shadedArtifactAttached enables the shaded artifact getting included in the deployment to the repo. could you explain shadedClassifierName? Does finalName have any impact on that? Is finalName just what the jar is called when packaging locally and shadedClassifierName is the name of the jar thats pushed to the repo? the docs arent clear to me there

Comment: also what is the maven command to download the dependency/uber jar to a specific local location?

Comment: Basicly both of calssifier and finalName are for controlling the name of artifacts. 
Each artifact may contain other packages (e.g. sources, tests, etc). The  `classifier` attribute specifies the content of that package based on filename convention: `${artifactId}-${version}-${classifier}.${packaging}`
So, if you use classifier you'll get files something like these:
`my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` ,`my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar` and `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-uber-jar.jar`

With `finalName` you will get:
`my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar` and `uber-jar.jar`

Comment: Just for clarification. `<finalName>` is the pattern which is used for naming the artifact and other packages. Default value is: `<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>`. Classifier is a suffix which is appended to `finalName` and it's for specify that additional package (source, test source, etc.). Here is a well-documented xsd: https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd